# Non-Permanent Air Conditioner for Townhomes

Tags: air-conditioning

I own my in townhome and my HOA specifies that I cannot have a through-wall or otherwise permanent air-conditioner. Additionally that window mounted units must be removed sometime in October. However the meager window mounted units are ugly and aren't efficient. I would like to get a split rail system but I am not sure if I could remove the outside component (is that called the inverter?) once October shows up. Is there anything on the market that will keep me cool and please my HOA?

Comment: Modern in-window units are acceptably efficient, especially if you focus on cooling the space you're actively using, and need not be "meager" -- I had one that cooled a 1200-square-foot apartment, and yes I mounted that monster every summer and dismounted it every winter.. The "portable" units which put only the ducts in the window are far less efficient and not  recommended.

Comment: Do you have an attic? Any chance of a roof mounted condensing unit? What type of heating unit do you have (if any)? Any restrictions on exhaust vents through walls or the roof?

Comment: Why the restrictive policy? If appearance, it's not clear that a window unit in place for 8 months a year is more attractive than a split unit compressor  outside for 12 months. If noise, modern mini splits can be quite quiet -- my neighbor put one in and it's quieter than his old window unit. I think it's some Mitsubishi model, some of their units are rated at [49 dB](http://www.mitsubishielectric.ca/en/hvac/PDF/m-series/Cooling-Heating_SingleIndoorUnit_Spec03.pdf) for the outdoor unit, which is [pretty quiet](http://www.industrialnoisecontrol.com/comparative-noise-examples.htm).

Comment: I will look into the exact reasoning. I just can't believe there isn't a split rail system that can be removed. I think I could mount a split rail with the condenser outside on the top deck. I was thinking of a mounting bracket that has clips like you find in cabinet doors. Mount the condenser on a plate which has the receiver ends of the mounting brackets on the bottom of the plate. Run the coolant lines right up to the windows and get removable snap-fit lines. The condenser could then be removed for the winter.

Comment: They don't make removable units, because disconnecting and reconnecting the refrigerant lines poses a huge technical challenge.  You'd need a connections method that could operate many thousands of times, without ever leaking a drop of refrigerant. The connection method must also withstand the operating pressures of the refrigerant, and never add any resistance to the flow.  It's simply not practical.